# Cambio de idioma con Django - i18n/setlang/ - Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

Error: Page not found 404 The current path, i18n/setlang/, didn’t match any of these.
¿Qué página busca?

Al implementar el sistema de internacionalización he creado mediante el comando para ello 3 archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo español tiene este ejemplo de contenido (**django.po**):

```
#: applications/home/templates/base.html:134
msgid "Restaurants"
msgstr "Restaurantes"
```

Por ejemplo una palabra del template lo he preparado para internacionalización y un selector de idioma:

Template **base.html**:

```
{% trans 'Restaurantes' %}



<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
              <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
                <select class="form-select" name="language">
                  {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                    <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Go" />
            </form>
```

El selector de idioma muestra los 3 idiomas disponibles, pero al elegir cualquiera de ellos y pulsar sobre "go" se muestra el siguiente error:

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**The current path, i18n/setlang/, didn’t match any of these.**

Comment: Has incluído las URLs de internacionalización (i18n) en el archivo `urls.py` de tu proyecto ?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'), ?

Comment: No, debería ser algo así: `url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))`